# How should I go about writing a PHP script to copy a web page?

Tags: php, web-scraping

I want to write a PHP script which, given a URL, copies the whole web page including images, scripts, stylesheets etc.

What's the best way to go about this, is there a tutorial around that will guide me through it?

I have some experience with PHP, but it's mostly based around forms, CMS's, cookies and databases.  How do I go about starting this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the contents of any page by doing this:

```
$url = "http://www.thisistheurl.com/";
$retries = 5;

while($retries > 0)
{
$contents = @file_get_contents($url);
if (strpos($http_response_headers[0],"200")
{
$retries = 0;
}
else {
$retries--;
}
}
```

You then have the entire page in the variable contents, you can either display it as is, or parse it using [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: That's great, do you have any tips about downloading the images, stylesheets, scripts etc?

Comment: Yes, in the parsing of DOMDocument, if you look you can find the function, getElementsByTagName, so you pull all script and link tags and use the same method to download those urls. Also, whenever I am taking content between sites externally like this, I always make it a class so you could make that above $this->downloadContents($file); and you would have a function for $this->getScripts() etc.